# Does anyone know of a jQuery FTP browser plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I want to navigate an FTP using a jQuery plugin. Does it exist?

Comment: Nope. You'll need a serverside backend to make it work, if at all. jQuery may look nice, but it is nothing more than JavaScript and Voodoo.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212150/js-ftp-web-directory-filelist

Comment: JavaScript does not handle FTP, if you need FTP client side in the browser, you probably need to write some Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might check out:

http://www.phpwebftp.com/

http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/

http://www.gleamtech.com/products/filevista/web-file-manager

http://yafm.sourceforge.net/

Another example (not sure it meets your requirements):

http://www.net2ftp.com/

And:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireftp/

Answer (score 0):

There is no jquery plugin to do this, but if you can use php there is a good solution, I tested it and it was great: 
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5045-PHP-Manage-files-and-directories-in-an-FTP-server.html