# Loading html elements and data from a remote server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm trying to load data to my index file remotely. I am able to do it locally with:

```
<body id="chk">
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#chk').load('a.html');
});
</script>
</body>
```

Which works flawlessly but it is really no use to me as I can't update the a.html file remotely. What I'm looking to achieve is something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#chk').load('ftp:/chkblabla.com/public_html/a.html');
});
```

But of course this doesn't load my data. Can it be done any other way? At the end, my goal is to load some string values to my app without having to make another build (Cordova).

Comment: why can't you update the file? How does that change when using ftp?

Comment: Check your console to see if you have CORS working fine.
Try a basic XMLHttpRequest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Why jquery, we are in 2018, use and learn native ecma js

Comment: @Luca Thanks for your response! It won't update because the index file is local on my tablet \ laptop and the a.html is located on my server. Locally everything works fine. I guess it's a cross origin problem. I wonder if there's any way around it..

Comment: Yeah, you must allow: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); on your server but your browser is blocking this from local networks, it is a security "feature" they said

Comment: @Cryptopat Thanks for your response! It won't load the content of a.html even with CORS plugin enabled. I thought it is not 'legal' to make a .load with an external url, only local.. So you're saying it should work.. That's good. What can I do to make it work? Thanks again.

Comment: Just by serving your file outside of your local network, from a server with cross-origin request enabled. Test it with https://www.test-cors.org/ .

Comment: @Cryptopat Thank you, I tried the website you sent, and the output I got is access-control-allow-origin: *
So it should allow it, no? But still does not work..

Comment: What exactly say your js console?

Comment: @Cryptopat jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 Failed to load ftp://my@domain.co.il/public_html/a.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: You need to serve your file in order to have an address like http://domain.co.il/public_html/a.html

Comment: @Cryptopat Could you kindly elaborate? maybe on a chat?

Comment: Your file isn't on a server, as the link isn't starting by http. Try this, for debugging: from a folder with your file a.html, type: php -S localhost:8000  . This will start a server, then the link to your file will be http:// localhost:8000/a.html put it on your script, and check the javascript console. It should works in windows too. Good luck

Comment: @Cryptopat It is on a server (starts with ftp) I just shortened the link. I tried your offer and when i link the .load() to http://localhost/a.html it loads wonderfully, but my problem still stands. Anyway, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Well, your code is okay but CORS, is only for HTTP/HTTPS. no ftp link. While loading a ftp file in a browser tab works, cors works based on http headers. Ftp does'nt have any http headers, this is why it fail. You must use http/https. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15100922/2494754

Answer (score 0):

You say "of course this does not load my data", but you don't explain why. Are you able to see javascript errors?

I'm always recommending to use `adb` to see the errors and warnings which come from the javascript engine: (at least for Mac OS)

```
adb logcat -v time | grep SystemWebChromeClient
```

If the problem is related to accessing external site, you will have to adapt your `index.html` at the line starting with

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"`

EDIT

I am not sure if this is relevant for you or not. A project I was developing two years ago was including this code:

```
<!-- include JQ, enable PhoneGap events under JQM, then include JQM -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        $.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled = true;
    });    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

HTH...

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond. I was under the impression that the jquery .load method only support loading files that are either both local or remote. I'm happy to see I'm wrong about it. So what's stopping the a.html contents (on my server) to load on my local index file and how can I fix it?

Comment: Google Chrome gives me this:  jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 Failed to load ftp://demo1@demo.co.il/public_html/a.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. Firefox gives me none, but doesn't display the a.html data either.

Comment: I am not sure that I can help you. I actually still missing the connection to Cordova. Anyway, I'll edit my answer with some script that my be relevant for you